# How can I draw a line in a python plot indicating 1 standard deviation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, standard-deviation

I have a plot from a data frame, I want to to draw a line indicating one standard deviation from the mean like in the picture below.

[image]

I know how to add text in the plot, but what I don´t know is how to add the line that represents the exact size of 1 standard deviation. In my plot, I fitted a 3 order polynomial and I draw two lines indicating 3 standard deviations from the fitted curve, but I haven´t come up with an idea in order to do what I intend. I would really appreciate your help. Next I put the current picture of my plot and my code
[image]

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func,date2num(x),y)
plt.plot(date2num(x), func(date2num(x),*popt), linestyle='--', linewidth=2, color='darkslategrey')
plt.plot(date2num(x), func(date2num(x),*popt)+(3*(np.sqrt(np.mean(func(date2num(GLE_48['Date and Time']),*popt))))), linestyle='--', linewidth=1.5, 
color='black')
plt.plot(date2num(x), func(date2num(x),*popt)-(3*(np.sqrt(np.mean(func(date2num(GLE_48['Date and Time']),*popt))))), linestyle='--', linewidth=1.5, color='black'
```

Comment: "Next I put the current picture of my plot and my code" I don't understand the problem. Why is this result wrong? What should it look like instead, and why?

Comment: Hi, the result is not wrong, what I did by fitting the curve and drawing the lines above and below the curve was an alternative for representing the standard deviation in the data distribution in the plot, but what I actually want to do, but do not know how to do it, is to represent the standard deviation like in the first picture (i.e., just by drawing the line indicating 1 standard deviation inside the plot). Sorry, probably it is so simple and I was not able to explain it very accurate.

Comment: "is to represent the standard deviation like in the first picture." I'm not clear on how the first picture does this. Now that I look closely, it seems that you have a small sigma character next to the short vertical line. Do you mean that this represents the size of the standard deviation for that data, and for your graph, you want to just draw the same sort of line? If so - *where* should it be drawn? How do you want to determine that?

Comment: "Do you mean that this represents the size of the standard deviation for that data, and for your graph, you want to just draw the same sort of line"- Yes! That is what I meant, the position of the line in the plot is not crucial, I know how to change the position and how to draw a line and also the sigma character, but if the line represents the size of the standard deviation, then that what I want to do in my plot.

Comment: "I know how to change the position and how to draw a line and also the sigma character, but if the line represents the size of the standard deviation, then that what I want to do in my plot." So... compute the standard deviation, and then draw a line with that length?

Comment: Well, thank you. Sorry for the time